# Unable to add childview to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView to display a tree based menu. I am surely missing something that is very basic and I need another eye to check my mistake. According to the library we create a view dynamically(basically a scrollview) and add it as a child to a RelativeLayout. Below is my layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reload_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="re load menu" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/reload_menu"></RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is how I am adding my root to this RelativeLayout

```
AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(getApplicationContext(), root);

    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    container.addView(tView.getView());
```

Even though this line of code executes without any exception, I do not see the treeview being displayed. I also checked tView.getView() and it looks perfectly fine. It's a scrollview. Can some one please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Your View has only one child view then using RelativeLayout is unnecessary. Use **FrameLayout** instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reload_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="re load menu" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/reload_menu"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**I change layout_height on match_parent**, if Your button should be above FrameLayout then set additional attribute `android:layout_below="@id/reload_menu"`, it will work even with match_parent attribute . Your main problem was i think match_content on **layout_height** because scroll view must have some height to adjust to it.

Try also use current context ( Activity code ):

```
AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(this, root); //this is Activity
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time in pointing out my issues. I would like to understand a little more. I have now changed the height to match_parent. In your code you are trying to set the height and width of the child(in this case tView). Since AndroidTreeView is part of the library, it does not have an implementation of setLayoutParams that I can use. Any other ideas that I can use to refresh the layout after adding the child?

Comment: If is not working maybe try change getApplicationContext() to this, if code is in activity.